# How many $ \ \text{3-to-1}$ functions from the set $A $ to $B$?

Tags: functions

Let $A$ and $B$ are two finite sets with $ \ |A|=15 \ $, $ \ |B|=5 $.

How many $ \ \text{3-to-1}$ functions from the set $A $ to $B$ ?

**Answer:**

Choose $3$ elements from the set $A$. We can choose $ 3$ elements in $ \binom{15}{3}$ ways and these $3$ elements can permute in $3!$ ways.

So there are a total $ \binom{15}{3} \times 3!$ ways in the set $A$.

Now each group of $3$ elements in $A$ can maps any one the $5$ elements of $B$.

Thus there are total $ \ \binom{15}{3} \times (3!) \times (5!) \ $ number of  $\text{3-to-1}$  functions.

**Am I right?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You choose three elements of $A$ to go to the first element of $B$.  The order does not matter because you are sending them all the same place.  As you say, you can do this in $15 \choose 3$ ways.  Now you choose three of the remaining $12$ to go to the second element of $B$, which you can do in $12 \choose 3$ ways.  Keep going.  You get
$${15 \choose 3}{12 \choose 3}{9 \choose 3}{6 \choose 3}{3 \choose 3}=\frac {15!}{(3!)^5}$$
There is a nice combinatorial proof of this.  You can order $A$ in $15!$ ways and send the first three to the first element of $B$ and so on.  The order of each group of $3$ does not matter for the function, so you divide by $(3!)^5$

Comment: That means there are $ \frac{15!}{(3!)^5} $ 3-to-1 functions.   But then the number of elements of the set $B$ does not matter

Comment: If $B$ had more than $5$ elements you would multiply by the number of ways to select five elements (one third of the number in $A$) to send $A$ to.